# How do you get past the seal in Sal Terrae?

Tags: genshin-impact

On this small island in Liyue, there is a seal blocking a hole where materials such as Violetgrass can be seen.

There is a tablet in front of the seal, presumably a puzzle of sorts to solve to open the seal. But I haven't found any solution that has worked.

[image]

How do you get past the seal in Sal Terrae?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 1.1 version this location is now unlocked during one of story quests:

> Zhongli's Historia Antiqua Chapter, Act I: [Sal Flore](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Sal_Flore)

Answer (score 3):

It seems [from this article](https://progameguides.com/genshin-impact/genshin-impact-salt-seals-the-ruin-within/) that it's not currently possible without glitching out of the map.

> all of your troubles are in vain, as currently, this barrier is not accessible in version 1.0 of the game. However, it may become a quest in update 1.1, but no one is sure at this present time.

There is [a map breaking glitch which allows you to fly and climb down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4TQo1zUBWI) into the area to collect the bits and bobs in there.